# Django model object initialization

Tags: python, django

If I do

```
obj = Object()
obj.att1 = 'test'
obj.att2 = 'test'
obj.save()
```

obj.id --> works fine

But if I do

```
obj=Object(att1='test',att2='test').save()
```

Doing obj.id --> obj seems to be Nonetype at this stage

Is this the case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know the exact framework you are using, but I am going to take a guess as to the problem:

`Object(att1='test',att2='test').save()`

The `save()` function doesn't appear to return the `Object` instance, it returns `None`.  So you would normally:

```
obj=Object(att1='test',att2='test')
obj.save()
```

Then check `obj.id`.

Comment: Thanks dclements. Your method works fine. Im using python language in Django framework by the way.

Comment: A Django one-liner that creates, saves, and returns the object is `Object.objects.create(att1='test', att2='test')`.

Comment: This is perfect answer. Because what you are doing is just two different things. In the first case you creating the object and obj is  OBJECT. The second case - the obj is the result of the FUNCTION.